# Python: Count uniques with multiple conditions

Tags: python, pandas, unique

I have a dataframe looking like:

| Company | Investor | Round | Investor type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| X | A | 1 | A |
| X | Undisclosed | 1 | A |
| X | A | 2 | A |
| X | Undisclosed | 2 | B |
| X | Undisclosed | 3 | A |
| X | Undisclosed | 3 | B |
| X | Undisclosed | 4 | B |
| X | Undisclosed | 4 | B |
| X | Undisclosed | 4 | B |
| Y | Undisclosed | 1 | A |
| Y | Undisclosed | 2 | B |
| Y | Undisclosed | 2 | B |
| Y | Undisclosed | 3 | A |
| Y | Undisclosed | 4 | B |
| Y | Undisclosed | 5 | B |

What I want to do is to create two new columns: Unique_A and Unique_B. The purpose of these are to have dummy variables if there is a "new" unique undisclosed investor that follows these rules:

1. If equal number of Undisclosed Investor of type A or B are found in round t+1, it shall be assumed that these undisclosed investors are the same and hence no new Investors shall be counted.
2. Example: If we have 1 Undisclosed investor of Investor type B in round 3 for company X, and 3 in round 4. The difference (3-1) shall be counted as a new investor. The results will look like following for this example dataframe:

| Company | Investor | Round | Investor type | Undisclosed A | Undisclosed B |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| X | A | 1 | A | 1 | 0 |
| X | Undisclosed | 1 | A | 0 | 0 |
| X | A | 2 | A | 0 | 0 |
| X | Undisclosed | 2 | B | 0 | 1 |
| X | Undisclosed | 3 | A | 0 | 0 |
| X | Undisclosed | 3 | B | 0 | 0 |
| X | Undisclosed | 4 | B | 0 | 0 |
| X | Undisclosed | 4 | B | 0 | 1 |
| X | Undisclosed | 4 | B | 0 | 1 |
| Y | Undisclosed | 1 | A | 1 | 0 |
| Y | Undisclosed | 2 | B | 0 | 1 |
| Y | Undisclosed | 2 | B | 0 | 1 |
| Y | Undisclosed | 3 | A | 0 | 0 |
| Y | Undisclosed | 4 | B | 0 | 0 |
| Y | Undisclosed | 5 | B | 0 | 0 |

Any help is greatly apreciated!

Comment: What's the logic behind a new `Undisclosed B` being added on the 12th row? (Following the previous identical 11th row)

Comment: @Ted. At row 12, there is a new company Y. So in that case we get two new B companies thus they get a dummy each as they are "new" for company Y.